# When ran the TestRunner.java file, asked "to implement missing steps", even when that same step was copied to stepDefinitions file

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

When I am starting off with a feature file, I have a simple 3 or 4 step feature file. When I ran the Runner file and the step definition stub methods are generated by JUnit in the console, I copied and pasted in to the step definitions file. My featue file is

```
  Scenario Outline: Navigate to Extract History page from the List 
 page

 Given the User logs into the PRAMA Datahub website successfully with 
  userId "" and passcode "<pacman_passcode>"
 Then the User lands on page “<title>”
When status column-cell has value “Ready”
When last run column-cell has “uId” and “some date” populated
Then the User is redirected to the extract page



 Examples:
   |  uId       | pacman_passcode         | title |
   | pnxxxutala | UL#3aLm@Qs%fT#%_@n_!47l | Datahub|
```

Later I added an additional @then step, which is duly reported as below, which I copied to the step definitions file and implemented the actions also. But still I am getting the same message again, and again. Why it is not recognizing the @then step, which was added ?

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:



 @then("^the User lands on page “Datahub”$")
   public void theUserLandsOnPageDatahub() { .  
   // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
   throw new PendingException();
   }
```

Also, I could not understand why the string "Datahub" is not passed as a parameter.

Your help is highly appreciated.